# How do I kill the first dragon encountered?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As part of the main storyline, I'm tasked with slaying a dragon outside of Whiterun. I follow Irileth and a bunch of other NPCs outside to confront the dragon, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to kill him.

What's the trick?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where are you? Who is the lady you're referring to? How far into the game are you?

Comment: I can't help but notice there is no punctuation and when you use no punctuation it makes it very difficult for us to understand your question and it makes it seem like one long run-on sentence and so please edit your question to make it more comprehensible

Comment: Wait, you can become a dane? What if you don't wanna go to Denmark? This question is incoherent. Please, clean it up and be more specific. Are you asking about the first dragon battle? Outside Whiterun?

Comment: @BlueRaja I sincerely hope the lack of punctuation in your comment was intentional =D

Comment: Agreeing with Mark. Which vikings? Which Dragon? Which inn? What do you mean when you say "become dane"? Do you mean "become thane"? The only "dane" I am able to find is Dane Olds, one of the devs.

Comment: possibly related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35930/6914

Comment: I took a stab based on what sounded like the events at the beginning of the game. If not, please clarify what encounter you're referring to.

Comment: I just read the original question and lol'd.

Answer (score 10):

It *sounds* like you're asking about the first dragon you fight, outside of Whiterun, as part of the quest *Dragon Rising*: you follow Irileth outside Whiterun and upon completing the quest:

> The Jarl makes you Thane.

If so, it's supposed to be an introductory dragonslaying encounter: if you followed Irileth around town before heading to the watchtower, you should have a fairly decent posse of guards to help you out.

To be honest, I was still learning how to use the controls on the PlayStation 3 version of the game at this point, and I essentially ran around the watchtower like a chicken with its head cut off. The guards and Irileth will do most of the work. I was a Conjuror build, so I summoned a Flame Atronach for good measure.

After a few minutes, the dragon will die pretty easily, whether you made a significant contribution to the fight or not.

Answer (score 2):

The basic way to kill dragon is :

- Attack from the ground with spells and/or bows
- When the dragon is grounded, use whatever you want and try to keep it grounded with the shouts you already know
- When Dragon HPs runs out, dragon dies.

Comment: And don't stand in the fire.

Comment: When on the ground, avoid head and tail. When he dies, don't stand too close: the erupting flames can burn your last HP.

Comment: I like that last step. That clarifies things. Does this apply to all monsters? :P

Answer (score 2):

Theres a small pillar at the foot of the steps, i used a bow to take shots at it while using the pillar to stay out of the dragons line of fire.

Answer (score 1):

When he is airborne shoot with a bow. When on land attack with with a one-handed weapon in one hand and a healing spell in the other.

Comment: How does one attack with a healing spell?

Answer (score 1):

Just run into the tower and wait inside, the other soldiers will kill him, and if he''s dead you also can take some guard clothes..

Answer (score 1):

The mission you are talking about is basically an introduction to killing dragons in Skyrim, all you have to do is shoot arrows at it until it lands, then use a 2 handed weapon to do maximum damage while it is down and with the guards help it is pretty easy to kill, if you still find it hard just lower the difficulty, get your level up by killing bandits or you can camp inside while the guards kill it.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the dragon pretty easily. Just use a bow and some iron arrows. The group of guards will have the aggro of the dragon, so just fire when you get the chance. You won't take damage and it'll take about 30 seconds to defeat it.