# How do I beat the Draugr Wight Lord at the end of Soljund's Sinkhole?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm running a totally vanilla character in Skyrim: Nord, half-casting (destruction), half-bashing (one-handed sword specialty), heavy armor.  I was on my way to Karstholm on the Blades quest and ran into [Soljund's Sinkhole](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Soljund%27s_Sinkhole).  I ran through it pretty easily solo, but got my butt handed to me by the Draugr Wight Lord at the end.  After several more solo attempts, drinking all sorts potions and whatnot, I gave up and ran past him, only to get my butt handed to me by the blood dragon waiting outside.  So, after reading [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35930/how-to-kill-a-dragon-in-skyrim), I headed back to town and picked up a companion (Lydia, from the Dragonsreach quests).  I thought I'd give another shot at the draugr before going after the blood dragon.  She didn't help much at all, or maybe I just don't know how to let her tank.

Any tips on how to beat this guy?  Are there switches that turn off the automagic fireball shooting thingy?  Are there especially effective attacks/spells/shouts that work?

Comment: FireBolt + Impact is the universal solution to any single, tough enemy for someone using destruction :)

Comment: What level were you? I was able to kill him using brute force only at level 17.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what you need to know about [Draugr Wight Overlord](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Draugr):

- He uses the disarm shout.  Its really annoying when he does so, especially against Lydia as NPCs typically don't go and pick up their weapons and will end up standing there.  Try giving her a nice staff and/or bow to use so she's out of the shout range instead.
- He's immune to poison and resists frost, so stick with fire or lightning.
- They hurt a lot up close with their enchanted weapons, and they have high armor.

Here are some typical strategies to use:

- Take advantage of the traps in the dungeon.  If there are any traps nearby, lead the draugr to it and have it hit them repeatedly.  You mentioned the fireball traps, position yourself so the lord is between you and the crystal.
- Take advantage of your own shouts, you can buy yourself some time by using just the FUS part of unrelenting force to stagger quite often (even better if you have the amulet of Talos and Talos' blessing).  Throwing in the bash from your shield to stagger them even more.
- Find some open spacing.  Other than the shout, the wight lords have no ranged attack, prick them to death with arrows.  (This is harder to do if you intend on saving Lydia as she'll most likely die).
- Give Lydia ranged attacks and just kite the lord around while keeping his attention.

If all else fails... [turn him into a sweet roll](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Wabbajack_(Skyrim))

Comment: OMG I didn't even know that thing existed and sweetrolls were a possibility.  Har!

Answer (score 4):

In the sinkhole run past the Draugr Wight Lord then head to the left of the statues that shoot fire at him and there is a tunnel. 
Follow this tunnel through and there will be a table with a Hallowed orc sword placed on it.
(This sword makes undead up to level 21 flee on hit, and this draugr is level 15).

Hit the Dragur Wight Lord once with the Hallowed orc sword and he should flee , so just keep chasing him and hitting him and you should be able to kill him without takin any damage. If he turns around to attack you, hitting him another time with the Hallowed orc sword, if your not already using it, will send him fleeing again so you can repeat this process until he is dead.

FYI I was level 12 when I did this :)

Answer (score 3):

What are your skill levels?

Automagic fireball shooting thingies are typically powered by soul gems, gems which can be removed by simply mousing over them and pressing E when prmpted (in the usual fashion).  I don't know if that will help but you might be able to disarm any thingies before the fight really gets going.

I believe Draugr are vulnerable to magic and fire.  Do you have an enchanted weapon that you can switch to for this fight that has extra magic or fire damage?  Are you a reliable enough caster that you can try to keep your distance and pelt him with fire/magic damage spells?  It's possible he's high level and using an Ebony weapon, which will hurt like the dickens.

I suggest disarming the traps and trying to rely on magic/fire damage. Barring that you might need to return at a later time.

Comment: In the end, this helped as much as @yx.'s answer.  If I could mark them both, I would ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I don't like that guy. I must have died 20+ times before this fool hardy strategy worked.

My charater:
Redgard, one-handed = 50; heavy armor = 40; 240 points Stamina; Glass sheild; Ebony Sword with 34 damage. Not sure, but I had like 110 armor points

Xbox 360, on master difficulty.

requirement: a sheild, 20 minor stamina potions and some stronger ones; Lydia with a sheild, and one-haned sword or mace. You'll need to remove better weapons from Lydias' inventory to force her to use the one-handed weapon and sheild.

strategy: Throw on some resist fire potions and alteration to raise you armor from the fire blast. Run in the room unarmed. Wait until he shouts, dodge it, them arm yourself. Hopefully Lydia, is still not attacking yet. Stay in the back, wait til he gets near you. Before he swings his sword, use ice form shout, if you have it, and hack at him till hes on his feet. Now before he swings on you, do shield bash, then swing your sword. Right after you swing, that is when Lydia should do a shield bash. If she does, then swing your sword again, otherwise do sheild bash then swing your sword. When your stamina is low, fill it up using the stamina potions, don't waste time switching to magic, removing your sheild. This can break the flow.

What should happen is you should sheild bash and both you and Lydia swing. Then Lydia should sheild bash, then both of you swing. Also sometimes Lydia will power swing causing him to stagger, so take advantage of that and get in a swing without using stamina. Also he should be focusing his swings on Lydia, so you should only be taking hits from the firebolts, but using a fortify and regenerate health potion should help with that.

It will take about 1-2 minutes before he's done.

Answer (score 1):

I've pretty seriously cheesed these fights in the past.

One thing I got used to was the disarm shout, which has very distinct animation where the guy will take in a deep breath.  When you see him inhale you can bring up the favorites menu and just switch out to dual spells or whatever, and switch back once it's over.

Another thing that has been mentioned here, but I can't stress enough, is other than their shout, they have no range.  I've danced around a table with one for a while, and at another point I was able to whirlwind sprint myself onto a ledge and just plink at him with my (incredibly pathetic) bow.

Answer (score 1):

Was pretty hard for me… I tried using the Freezing shout on him only to discover that he was regenerating health even while frozen. For the first few attempts, I tried using destruction magic from far, but he kept running back and regenerating. So, finally I had to fus-ro-dah him to the ground and run past it to the ledge, where a combination of:

- fortify one-handed
- fortify block
- damage stamina  poison
- j'zargo's flame scrolls
- more fus-ro-dah

… and timely blocking took him down.

Answer (score 1):

Well I did it on my first attempt at level 37, and key to my success was Mjoll the lioness from the rift. Follow the questline and recover her grimsever and she will yours. Also for marriage it's a good thing because she is so strong. I'm level 37 and she tanks more than me - she can solo a dragon!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i've found is to get the scroll of conjure storm atronach from the chest behind the altar. To do this just have him chase you away from the chest, knock him down with your shout, then get into the chest.The atronach will do most of the work and all you have to do is shoot firebolts or arrows at him from a safe distance.

Answer (score 1):

Having tried most of the strategies already mentioned (mostly useful, but the drops for chests and on the alter seem to be random so I got none of those useful objects), I still got my ass handed to me.

Then I tried distracting him with my Fire Atronach and attacking him with the Wabbajack (using the tunnel for cover). You could use scrolls or your follower for similar distraction, or simply stand out of reach. After three hits he turned into a smoking pile and it rained gold. I guess if all else fails, luck helps (as well as Deadric magic). Seriously, though.

I do recommend picking the Wabbajack up for just such situations. It is a quest reward for completing The Mind of Madness. If an enemy is already so strong you can't kill it, you have nothing to lose by using it. At the very least, you should do some decent damage with it from the safety of standing next to the statues. Warning - it can result in turning a target into a Dremora or summoning another enemy, but as I said: if you are trying everything above and still not making a dent, you have nothing to lose (and septims to gain).

Answer (score 1):

Playing on master/PS3. Level 17.

You need a lot of arrows. Disarm all weapons. As one poster said above, run to the area beside the fire pillar where he can't follow. There is a pillar to the left of the chest (as you're facing it from beside the fire pillar). When he goes into the tunnel walk down beside the pillar so that the fireballs strike the other side, but you have a clear view into the tunnel he comes from. When he walks down to get ya, for some reason he stalls near the chest (did for me anyway). Head-shot him with arrows, quick-de-equip bow when you see him start the spell animation. Use your flame shout for more damage. He may at times move to his right and come around the table. Go back to the fire pillar area and wait for him to go back to the tunnel. Repeat.

Took a couple hundred arrows. He will heal himself throughout, but your arrows (especially the critical hits - you did get the crit perk for archery right?) and shouts should get him down to a point where he drops to his knees. Quickly equip your best weapon and power hit him. One shot should put him down.

Answer (score 0):

I used firebolts with stagger. You have to upgrade to the perk obviously and use magic. His only ranged attack is his shout, which is a pain if you are trying to use one or two handed. Whenever I saw him about to shout, I would use my force shout to stagger him then pull out my Firebolts and stagger him until I was out of magic, then I switched to my bow (which also had stagger) and shot him and hoped he didn't use his shout before mine was back. It can be an annoying way to beat him but for me it was easiest.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to lower the difficult level of the game. I was playing the game at a novice level from the beginning and it's not very hard. When I'm more comfort with the game I've changed to apprentice level.

Answer (score 0):

I was level 15, and I just stowed my pride, set the difficulty to easy, hit him with double lightening as long as I could and finished him with a double handed weapon.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I really can't be bothered with most boss fights including dragons.

Answer (score 0):

You kill the vampire (with your mighty battleaxe), retreat back to the room with the levers controlling the three revolving doors. If you time it right, the draught will get caught in the fireball trap. Just sit back and have a bite and a glass of wine. When you no longer hear the sound of fireballs, it's all over.