# When or where do Legendary dragons appear in the world?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I heard about these dragons on this site and was curious to know, when do legendary dragons appear in the world? Is there a step-by-step guide to getting them to appear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to kill a dragon in Skyrim?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35930/how-to-kill-a-dragon-in-skyrim)

Comment: @Slurpee OP is asking about legendary dragons specifically; he's not asking how to kill them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Legendary variants of dragons were added for high-level players; they begin to appear at around level 78. Once you get that high, they can be found just like any regular dragon (although they are not *guaranteed* to spawn): randomly in the wilderness, at word walls, et cetera.

Note that Legendary dragons were added by the Dawnguard DLC, so you'll need that.

Once they spawn, fighting them is basically the same as [any other dragon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35930/how-to-kill-a-dragon-in-skyrim) (except they are stronger and have a wider variety of shouts). There's more information on them at the [UESP wiki for Skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Legendary_Dragon#Legendary_Dragon).

Comment: I have a bit of leveling to do then...

Answer (score 9):

There is a guaranteed spawn at Arcwind Point.

[From Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Dragon):

> A legendary dragon can also always be found at Arcwind Point perching
>   above a sarcophagus that contains either a Draugr Deathlord or a
>   Dragon Priest.
>
> This spawning point still requires the The Elder Scrolls V: Dawnguard
>   DLC and level 78+. If the player dose not meet these requirements,
>   another type of dragon will spawn at Arcwind Point.

Comment: Can confirm: went to Arcwind Point, instant Legendary Dragon

Comment: The wiki page is correct again in 2019.

Answer (score 3):

You generally have to be lv 78 and have dawnguard installed, but their are people who have encountered them anywhere in-between lvs 50 through 77. I've seen the videos but it is extremely rare and they can spawn anywhere they can spawn in whiterun, windhelm, winter hold, excetera.

Answer (score 0):

You need dawnguard and to be lvl 78+

Answer (score -1):

I read the website and it said they spawn at level 78 but they can come before that. Some people found them at level 50 and I watched videos as proof. It just gets less rare when you're around their level. Blades kinda help well. Give new locations where to find all types of dragons.

Comment: Please add a source to your claim.

Answer (score -2):

At level 66 I encountered a Legendary Dragon at Winterhold. It was the first time I'd ever encountered one (and it was badass!).

I'm not sure if it is intended or not, the only mod I've got installed which might have changed it somehow is Deadly Dragons.